# JQuery UI drag and drop show alert when item goes to destination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery UI's sortable for drag and drop. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neLvo3e2/ Code is below.

Now I want to know when an item has been dropped into a destination box. Basically **show an alert that tells me which item was put where**. How do I accomplish this?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 600px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
</ul>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

*stop()* sortable's event is your best solution here, you can grab out the dragged item and from where it was been dragged from the **ui** variable:

https://jsfiddle.net/f21f9qan/1/

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <style>
      #sortable1, #sortable2 {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        width: 142px;
        min-height: 600px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
        margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 120px;
      }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
          stop: function(e, ui){
            var item = ui.item[0].innerHTML;
            var from = ui.sender?"not the same sortable":"same sortable";
            alert("dragged:" + item + " from: " + from);
          }
        }).disableSelection();
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
    </ul>


    </body>
```

See full documentation here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

Comment: I see your logic here and the stop function is my best bet, however, your Fiddle has a bug? it always says "same sortable" even if the item comes from another box